# Angular JS disable binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, clone

I am new to AngularJS and Java Script. I understand that Java Script is pass by reference(As I understood, objects will be passed by reference and primitive data type will not be).

My problem is I have some records displayed in table, when user click on a column, I open a pop up and display radio button options using the object passed from parent screen.

This pop up has save and cancel.  but due to angular binding, any changes made immediately affects the object, so even if the user cancels, the changes are reflected.

Now cloning is one option with its drawbacks and next is disable angular binding for this popup. I know there are various options available. But as I am new to both technologies, it would be great help, if you can suggest the best way and pointers.

Comment: to avoid directly editing original use `angular.copy()` , then when saves can use `angular.extend()` to pass changes back to original

Comment: @charlietfl  It worked.  I should read the documentation. If you can add you comment as answer, I can accept it. Thanks